# Coalescing operator vs Ternary operator

Tags: c#

```
int? x = null;
int z = x ?? 10; //This works perfectly
z = (x != null) ? x : 10; //Won't compile , z must be a nullable type
```

What is the **difference** between these two operators? Why the compiler does not complain about the coalescing operator? The **z** variable is not a **nullable type** still, if **x** wouldn't be null it can be assigned to **z**. Why this behaviour is different with the ternary operator? Interesting.

Comment: I'm just guessing here, but I assume the compiler doesn't check for whether or not x *can* be null in the ternary statement. It simply looks at the argument *types* and determines that the best return type for the ternary is `int?`.

Comment: seems that the compiler just isn't as smart as we'd hope in this scenario

Comment: @Widi No, it's fine to compare nullables to null.

Comment: @Widi, checking for equality to null is the same as checking for HasValue, in this circumstance.

Comment: And by the way, you can provide the compiler with the hint it needs.  If *you* know the `int?` can't be null, simply cast or use its value member.

Comment: z=  x ?? 10; //This works perfectly because at compile we know z can never be null due to  right side value which is 10. even with out evaluating x.

z = (x != null) ? x : 10;  // here we do not because (x != null)  it is evaluated at runtime.

Comment: @sm.abdullah that makes perfect sense sir! Interesting! Thank you!

Comment: @sm.abdullah, I don't think that actually follows. *We* know looking at that ternary statement, even at compile time, that it can't return null. Won't happen. Does not have anything to do with runtime vs compile time. It's simply an inference that the C# compiler doesn't make, for one reason or another.